# Does application built using Kotlin Multiplatform use platform's native memory management implementation?

Tags: kotlin, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

Kotlin/Native has its own memory management implementation. When building a mobile app using Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile(KMM), what's the role of Kotlin/Native's implementation of memory management. For example, if an App is built using KMM would it use Kotlin/Native's memory management instead of ARC(Automatic Reference Counting) which is memory management implementation of Swift?

Comment: Possibly related: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/05/kotlin-native-memory-management-update/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will use Kotlin/Native's current deferred reference-counting garbage collector, which was chosen for simplicity.

Though the memory management model is under change and likely to get it's first new developer preview by the end of this year's summer.
For more information about the changes you can read this post: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/05/kotlin-native-memory-management-update/

Comment: How is Kotlin/Native able to override the platform's memory management implementation? For example, how does iOS know to use Kotlin/Native's deferred reference-counting garbage collector instead of ARC

Comment: But if I instantiate an "Kotlin" object in an iOS function, who will deallocate the object after the function scopes finishes? Kotlin MM or iOS ARC?